# Copiar dados de um campo para outro

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Meu cliente, solicitou que eu criasse 2 campos no sistema, um como "Celular" outro como "WhatsApp" e que ao lado do campo WhatsApp tivesse um botão para copiar o valor, caso o numero seja o mesmo, alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: Não está muito claro o que deseja. Poderia ser mais específico? Mostrar o código que possui hoje pode ser de boa ajuda

Comment: @Randrade são dois campos de telefone, um para celular, outro para Whatsapp, porém algumas pessoas tem o mesmo numero para ambos, e ai, ele quer copiar o valor do telefone para colar no whatsapp, mas seria assim, clica no botão, ele já pega o valor que tá no celular, e passa para o campo whatsapp

Comment: Eu ainda não fiz nada... tenho apenas a tela (CRUD) gerada pelo scaffold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sem muito detalhe fica difícil de te ajudar, mas, usando jQuery, a base é essa

```js
$('#bt-copiar').on('click', function(){
  $('#txt-wpp').val($('#txt-tel').val());    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Telefone:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt-tel" />
<button id="bt-copiar">Copiar</button>

<br>

<label>Whatsapp</label>
<input type="text" id="txt-wpp" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Somente com JavaScript você pode fazer algo desta forma:

```js
function copiaValor() {
  var celular = document.getElementById("campo1").value;
  document.getElementById("campo2").value = celular;
}
```

```html
<label>Telefone:</label>
<input type="text" id="campo1" />

<br>

<label>Whatsapp</label>
<input type="text" id="campo2" />

<button id="copiar" onclick="copiaValor()">Copiar</button>
```